# JAVASCRIPT Problem with regex in the .split() method

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string formed by number and mathematical operator like `"1 + 1 *1"` that is the text content of the number appendend on the screen div, I want to form an array of them  and then divide it using mathematical operators such as + or - as a divisor, the problem is that when I try to divide them the array is actually divided, except for when the "-" sign is present, in fact if I have as a string `"1 + 1 * 1 -1"` the result will be an array `["1", "1", "1-1"]` while it should be `["1", "1", "1", "1"]`
Thanks everyone in advance.

```
let regex = /[+ | - | * | / ]/
let Arrays
Arrays = screen.textContent.split(regex);
```

Comment: Why do you repeat space and `|` characters in your character set?

Comment: You need to escape `-` inside `[]` because it's used for ranges like `0-9` or `a-z`.

Comment: You have to escape `/` because it's the regexp delimiter.

Comment: Sample input has no space after ```-``` and ```1```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing alternatives with character sets.

Put the operators inside a character set, and optional spaces around it.

You need to escape `-` because it's used to separate the ends of a character range (unless you put it at the beginning or end of the character set).

```js
let regex = /\s*[+\-*/]\s*/;
let text = '1 + 1 * 1 -1';
console.log(text.split(regex));
```

Comment: `/[/]/` is a valid regex. Most meta characters don’t need to be escaped in character sets. `/\s*[+\-*\/]\s*/` can also be written as `/\s*[+*/-]\s*/`. `/[/]/` is often used as a more readable alternative to `/\//`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure about `/` because it also delimits the regexp. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I prefer to escape `-` rather than rely on the specific position in the character set, it's more robust when editing.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

Splitting the string at `+, -, *, /`

```js
let screentextContent = "1 + 1 * 1 -1"
let regex = /[+\-*/]/
let Arrays
Arrays = screentextContent.split(regex);
console.log(Arrays)
```

white space after 1 or before 1 will be preserved.

Comment: ```|``` is like or, that means either of +, -, *, /; But here I think it is not needed since ```[]``` is used for set

Comment: since ```|``` is part of  character set string will split for ```|```  also.

Comment: yes it's an OR, if is wrong sorry guys for my error i've began to learn regex just today.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const str = "1 + 1 * 1 - 1";
let regex = /[+|\-|*|/]/
let arr
arr = str.split(regex).map(itm => itm.trim());
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What are the `|` supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe OP would've used it for something like `OR`, I just copied his version.

Comment: That's what I assume as well, but I'd expect an answer to correct that. (Or in the least mention it.) Repeating the same character within a character class doesn't make much sense.